# Duplicate a row in dataframe and flip columns in the duplicated row

Tags: r

I have R code which duplicates a row, and flips `HomeTeam` and `AwayTeam` columns, renames them, and adds `home` column. It looks like this

```
goal_model_data_part1 <- internationals %>%
  select(HomeTeam, AwayTeam, FTHG) %>%
  cbind(home = 1) %>%
  rename(
    team = HomeTeam,
    opponent = AwayTeam,
    goals = FTHG
  )

goal_model_data_part2 <- internationals %>%
  select(AwayTeam, HomeTeam, FTAG) %>%
  cbind(home = 0) %>%
  rename(
    team = AwayTeam,
    opponent = HomeTeam,
    goals = FTAG
  )

goal_model_data <- rbind(goal_model_data_part1, goal_model_data_part2)
```

So, for example, Data like this

```
HomeTeam,AwayTeam,FTHG,FTAG
Italy,Turkey,3,0
```

Will be converted to this

```
team,opponent,goals,home
Italy,Turkey,3,1
Turkey,Italy,0,0
```

My code works perfect but since I am new to R I wonder if there is a way to simplify it?

Comment: `goal_model_data_part1 <- internationals %>%
  select(HomeTeam, AwayTeam, FTHG) %>%
  cbind(home = 1) %>%
` @akrun

Comment: `cbind(home = 1)` it's one for Italy because they are playing home. for Turkey I add 0 since they are playing away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially the same as what you did but avoiding `rename` step and intermediary variable creation.

```
library(dplyr) 

internationals %>%
  select(team = HomeTeam, opponent = AwayTeam, goals = FTHG) %>%
  mutate(home = 1) %>%
  bind_rows(internationals %>%
  select(team = AwayTeam, opponent = HomeTeam, goals = FTAG) %>%
  mutate(home = 0))

#    team opponent goals home
#1  Italy   Turkey     3    1
#2 Turkey    Italy     0    0
```

Answer (score 2):

We could do this with a group_by summarise

```
library(dplyr)
internationals %>% 
   rowwise() %>% 
   summarise(team = c(HomeTeam, AwayTeam),
     opponent = c(AwayTeam, HomeTeam), goals = c(FTHG, 0), 
       home = c(FTAG, FTHG > 0),
        .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 2 x 4
team   opponent goals  home
  <chr>  <chr>    <dbl> <int>
1 Italy  Turkey       3     0
2 Turkey Italy        0     1
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. for the second row it should be `Turkey,Italy` as in my example

Comment: another comment, i subset specific columns `select(HomeTeam, AwayTeam, FTHG)` because my dataframe contains lots of unrelevant columns i don't need

Comment: @rel1x If you are using `select`, then within `select` itself you can rename, instead of having a new line of code

Comment: @rel1x in your original data, how many rows are there.  Is it still one row

Comment: thanks a lot for your quick answer but I decided to go with Ronak Shah's solution because it looks more elegant to me and works perfect. thanks again for your help!